# Is any nextjs file/component structure visualisation exist?

Tags: file, next.js, structure

I have a nestjs project as a hobby. I have been making it maybe once in 2 weeks, when I have time from my common work and family.
But all the time, because of huge time lag of doing it, I forgetting file structure.
Is there any way to visualate in any type of diagrams, the file/component structure?

Comment: Maybe worth giving their new [DevTools](https://devtools.nestjs.com/login) a shot.